# How to obtain the row and column of selected cell in PySimpleGUI?

Tags: python, user-interface, events, pysimplegui

I have some tabular data, that I want displayed in my GUI. I am using PySimpleGUI.

I am building on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68034618/847773).

```
        [sg.Table(values=data_values, headings=data_headings,
                        max_col_width=65,
                        col_widths=data_cols_width,
                        auto_size_columns=False,
                        select_mode=sg.TABLE_SELECT_MODE_BROWSE,
                        justification='left',
                        enable_events=True,
                        num_rows=6, key='_tracker_')]
```

The table has enabled events, hence every click on it creates a event with the key value.

```
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == "_tracker_":
        print(values["_tracker_"])
```

I can obtain the row of the click with `values["_tracker_"]` . Can I get the column as well?

Basically I want the event to be triggered only when the table is clicked in a specific column, while the row of the event is variable. Hence, I thought the best way was to check events on whole table and than filter out based on row and column.

If there is a completely other way to do this, I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can work by tkinter code.

- `event` stored in `element.user_bind_event`
- Find region clicked by method `identify('region', x, y)` of widget of element.
- Identify which row by method `identify_row(y)` of widget of element.
- Identify which column by method `identify_column(x)` of widget of element.

Here's my code for it.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme("DarkBlue3")

newlist = [[f"Cell ({row+1}, {col+1})" for col in range(8)] for row in range(10)]
COL_HEADINGS = ["Date", "Ref", "ID", "Owner", "Customer", "Price", "Size", "Path"]
layout = [
    [sg.Table(values=newlist, headings=COL_HEADINGS, max_col_width=25,
        num_rows=10, alternating_row_color='green', key='-TABLE-',
        enable_events=True, justification='center',)],
    [sg.Text("", size=(50, 1), key='-Position-')]
]

window = sg.Window('Table', layout, finalize=True)
table = window['-TABLE-']
table.bind('<Button-1>', "Click")
position = window['-Position-']
position.expand(expand_x=True)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == '-TABLE-':
        pass
    elif event == '-TABLE-Click':
        e = table.user_bind_event
        region = table.Widget.identify('region', e.x, e.y)
        if region == 'heading':
            row = 0
        elif region == 'cell':
            row = int(table.Widget.identify_row(e.y))
        elif region == 'separator':
            continue
        else:
            continue
        column = int(table.Widget.identify_column(e.x)[1:])
        position.update(f"Table clicked at ({row}, {column})")

window.close()
```

Comment: Only one question: Why do you still call the -TABLE- event?

Comment: Default, there's another event generated when `"<<TreeviewSelect>>"`, just give another option if selection required, can be skipped if not necessary. Basically, `Treeview` widget of `tkinter` is the `Table` element of `PySimpleGUI`.